# Make an Iso-File

Tags: iso

I have changed the Ubuntu installation file 22.04.3 and want to create a new iso file.

The iso file should also start when secure boot is activated.
This should be possible with mkisofs. Unfortunately, I have not yet succeeded in creating the iso file.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: If the target computers are similar enough, you can create a master system, an installed system with all the bells and whistles [prepared for OEM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview), make an image of it and then clone from the image to the other computers. Installed systems are rather portable, but there are problems, when some but not all computers need a proprietary kernel driver (typically for graphics or wifi). - This is much easier that to create a custom iso file (a 'respin' of Ubuntu).